# Obfuscate Android app with Proguard results in fatal exception when starting app on device with official download and licensing libraries

Tags: java, android, proguard

I tried to obfuscate a finished app which is written totally in C++ only the download and licensing is written in java. It works without using proguard very well, but once it is obfuscated I get following error when starting the application on the phone.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fantasyhaze.rememory/com.fantasyhaze.rememory.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MetadataColumns: , while compiling: SELECT APKVERSION,_id,DOWNLOADSTATUS,DOWNLOADFLAGS FROM MetadataColumns LIMIT 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1840)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1861)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MetadataColumns: , while compiling: SELECT APKVERSION,_id,DOWNLOADSTATUS,DOWNLOADFLAGS FROM MetadataColumns LIMIT 1
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1438)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1406)
    at N.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at N.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.fantasyhaze.rememory.GameActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.fantasyhaze.rememory.Main.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1804)
    ... 11 more
```

I used following configs in the proguard.cfg

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public interface com.google.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers public class com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadsDB { 
    public static final java.lang.String * ; 
}
```

When building the app it gives a few warnings, which I don't know how to resolve when using the play_licensing and play_apk_expansion stuff.

```
-obfuscate:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\bin\proguard
      [jar] Building jar: D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\bin\proguard\original.jar
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 4.7
 [proguard] Reading program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\bin\proguard\original.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_apk_expansion\downloader_library\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_licensing\library\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_apk_expansion\zip_file\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar]
 [proguard] Preparing output jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\bin\proguard\obfuscated.jar]
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\bin\proguard\original.jar]
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_apk_expansion\downloader_library\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_licensing\library\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [D:\SlidersEdgeUniverse\FloWars\CPE\trunk\Rememory\Source\PRO_Android\lib\play_apk_expansion\zip_file\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [annotations.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message in the first posting

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fantasyhaze.rememory/com.fantasyhaze.rememory.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MetadataColumns: , while compiling: SELECT APKVERSION,_id,DOWNLOADSTATUS,DOWNLOADFLAGS FROM MetadataColumns LIMIT 1

indicates that there is a problem with the SQLite database, since a required table is missing.

I would suggest to decompile the APK file with [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) for example and then look into the Java class files with [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to find out which Java class files a missings or have been obfuscated in a way, resulting an application crash ..

For my personal experience most problems with Proguard are related to classes where certain necessary properties have been obfuscated in a bad way or the classes have just been removed during the obfuscation process.

Statements like

> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

in your proguard.pro file allow you to exclude classes from Proguard's obfuscation process

Comment: Well I have tried a lot but did not found a solution ... but thx for the link to dex2jar and JD-GUI!

Answer (score 1):

I recently came upon this error, it seems that after obfuscating the code, reflection stops working on `DownloadsDB` class. The problem stems on the issue that inside the `DownloadsContentDBHelper.onCreate` method it retrieves the nested classes declared through reflection and at least on my case no classes were returned.

So I replaced the line

```
Class<?>[] arrayOfClass = DownloadsDB.class.getDeclaredClasses();
```

with

```
 Class<?>[] arrayOfClass = new Class[] {MetadataColumns.class, DownloadColumns.class};
```

manually specifying the classes required. Class fields are also accessed by name and so I instructed proguard to completely keep the class and all members:

```
-keep class com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadsDB* {*;}
```

that seems to do the trick for me.